# How much extra workload would I assign the GPU if I choose to duplicate the screen instead of a single monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, performance, gpu

As per my very little knowledge about computer graphics, I think the effect would be minimal. The reason is, given that the two screens has the same resolution, the pixel calculations are done exactly once and only the 'writing to framebuffer' operation is done twice given that the two screens has the same resolution, which is the last step of the graphics pipeline.

How much of a workload is the last step compared to the rest of the pipeline? Would the effects be minimal, i.e., If I duplicate the screens, would my not-so-powerful GPU have trouble maintaining a reasonable FPS rate when playing games due to duplicating the screens?

Comment: This heavily depends on the type of graphics card and how they implemented it. The only thing that helps here is a benchmark.

Comment: @ThomasKilian do you have any benchmark software recommendation for such scenario? How can I test this, which parameters should I take into consideration?

Comment: Benchmarks are unfortunately countless. Try a couple. Run them with single and duplicated monitor and compare the performance counters. Finding a benchmark with reasonable counters is stupid work :-( Eventually simply use a stop watch.